# Rails accepts_nested_attributes for: eliminating duplicates

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nested-attributes, validates-uniqueness-of

Say we've got the following models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :widgets
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :widgets, allow_destroy: true
end

class Widget < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    validates :title, presence: true, uniqueness: { scope: [:user_id] }
end
```

When I save a user with nested widget attributes that contain a duplicate title I get a validation error as expected.  What's a good way to avoid the validation error and silently eliminate the duplicate entries before saving?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could just reject the nested attributes if they don't match certain criteria:

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :widgets,
  allow_destroy: true,
  reject_if: lambda { |w| Widget.pluck(:title).include?(w.title) && Widget.pluck(:user_id).include?(w.user_id) }
```

Comment: This does not consider duplicate attributes in memory though.  For example: `user.widgets_attributes = { '0' => { title: 'Foo' }, '1' => { title: 'Foo' }}` would still attempt to save the duplicate.